# Run macro in shared workbook and protect it

Tags: excel

I want to run a macro in a shared workbook. My macro as below.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ss"
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect
```

When I run the macro without sharing it works fine. When share it below error prompts:

> Unprotect method of Worksheet class failed.

Can anyone help to run my macro in shared environment and keep the sheet in protection?

Comment: What do you mean by 'share'. Do you mean you email it or is this some new Excel option?

Comment: what i mean by share is excel option to allow multiple users to work in same  excel.

Comment: @MaduraSaddhathilaka Check if this works below. If so please accept answer as there is no real answer for this on SO

Comment: Note upon further research this is not possible in Excel. Refer to answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of Excel.

Sheets can't be protected or unprotected whilst shared. No way around it short of changing Excel itself. Afraid there's no other way.

You'll also notice that you can't manually unprotect the sheet whilst it is shared as well.